# Regexp split string with additional conditions

Tags: python, regex, split, conditional-statements

I have string like

```
a = 'text1, text2 (subtext1, subtext2), text3'
```

Need split that string on parts by comma-symbols, but only those that are not in the frame brackets:

```
splited = ['text1', 'text2 (subtext1, subtext2)', 'text3']
```

How make that with regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion based regex.

```
>>> a = 'text1, text2 (subtext1, subtext2), text3'
>>> re.split(r',(?![^()]*\))', a)
['text1', ' text2 (subtext1, subtext2)', ' text3']
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', a)
['text1', 'text2 (subtext1, subtext2)', 'text3']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nN2qZ7/1)

**OR**

Positive lookahead based regex.

```
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))', a)
['text1', 'text2 (subtext1, subtext2)', 'text3']
```

Comment: tested this with PHP `preg_split()` and it works the same. nice job!

Comment: you could use all the regexes used in python on php.

Comment: yes, but not always so for javascript, so i wanted to explicitly confirm it for anyone coming her who may wonder